# Java Package in Eclipse greyed out and Program unable to find file

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to put my javaFX FXML files into their own package. Whenever I do the package becomes greyed out and even though it shows as it should in my file system when I try to run the program it cannot find the files and gives me a load exception error.

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGcek.png)

Comment: Please tell us more specifically what you did exactly in which order.

Comment: I imported this project. I made the application.view package. Then I moved the FXML files to the package. Then i change the path in the main file to the new one which is application/view/Main.FXML. When i try to run i get the errors

Comment: The package is shown differently because it does not contain Java classes (it just looks grayed-out in your installed theme). The errors says `Main.fxml` is found but loading fails in line 11 (`Main.fxml:11`). By the way, the theme you have installed might cause issues and slow down Eclipse.